# Content-type header not supported

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, libcurl

I am following this link for elasticsearch.

```
https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-practical-introduction-to-elasticsearch
```

I am trying following curl to post the json data.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @D:\data\shakespeare.json
```

But I am getting error like below:

```
{
  "error" : "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported",
  "status" : 406
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the content type in the header to application/json:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @D:\data\shakespeare.json
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I already fixed it curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @D:\data\shakespeare.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Answer (score 7):

I received the same error after updating from an older version to 6.x.x. I'm not using curl statements directly, I'm using python's elasticsearch plugin.

In my case, I needed to install the newer version of the plugin that corresponded to the updated elasticsearch server.

pip install elasticsearch==6.3.1

Make sure you run it in the same Python Environment that your code is executing in.

Hope this saves someone some headache.

Comment: I am trying with elasticsearch 8.2 and docker image 8.2 and I get a similar error message

Comment: i was also using 7.x.x and using 8.x.x worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution you can set a default header that will overwrite previous header:

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient
    .builder(new HttpHost(url, port, scheme))
    .setDefaultHeaders(new Header[]{
        new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    })
    .build();
```

Comment: This solution solved the Content-Type header issue, but then I got a new error: "Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header"

Comment: @PauloMerson Same error I received.

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74715712/7792357