# Can I use elasticsearch-java with elasticsearch 7.5.2?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I hava tried many version of elasticsearch-java but none of it can work.
So, my elasticsearch version is **7.5.2**, and the error resonse is like this:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [***:80], URI [/location/_search?typed_keys=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7] is not supported","status":406}
```

When I trying to set the default header like this:

```
setDefaultHeaders(new Header[]{
    new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
})
```

And the error response changed to this:

```
co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/search] Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header. Please check that you are connecting to an Elasticsearch instance, and that any networking filters are preserving that header.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Elastic Java API Client is [forward-compatible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/introduction.html#_elasticsearch_server_compatibility_policy) and not backward. So you can not use it with Elastic 7.5 version. You can use it only with the 7.16 or greater version.

[Elasticsearch Java high level client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html) you can use with 7.5 version but it is deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks! I'll still use high level client instead.

Comment: Sure. if it helps you then accept answer .

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @puppylpg answer, I tested below code and worked fine.

```
SSLContext sslContext = TransportUtils
            .sslContextFromCaFingerprint(fingerprint);

    BasicCredentialsProvider credsProv = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProv.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(login, password)
    );

    // Create the low-level esClient
    RestClient restClient = RestClient
            .builder(new HttpHost(esHost, esPort, protocol))
            .setDefaultHeaders(new Header[]{
                    new BasicHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
            })
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(hc -> hc
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProv)
                    .addInterceptorLast( (HttpResponseInterceptor)
                            (response, context) ->
                                    response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch"))

            ).build();

    // Create the esTransport with a Jackson mapper
    ElasticsearchTransport esTransport = new RestClientTransport(
            restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

    // And create the API esClient
    ElasticsearchClient esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(esTransport);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `elasticsearch-java` client if you prefer it than high level rest client, which is deprecated already.

All you have to do is to add default `X-Elastic-Product: Elasticsearch` header for all the responses by low version elasticsearch server like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74102828/7676237).

As for the `Content-type: application/json` request header, it may be optional(eg: no need to add this header for requests to 7.12.x elasticsearch). However, in your situation(7.5.2), this header should exist.

**Note: keep in mind that the elasticsearch-java client may not be totally compatible with low version elasticsearch server even if the response header check is passed.**

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses spring data approach (maybe to have repository abstraction and other features) with ClientConfiguration and had the same problem (in my case I was connecting elasticsearch-java 8.6.2 to elasticsearch 7.13.1 and got a org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException), maybe will find this useful:

```
package com.myapplication.configuration;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchClients.ElasticsearchClientConfigurationCallback;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchConfiguration;

import co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportUtils;

import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchClientConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${elastic.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elastic.port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("${elastic.fingerprint}")
    private String fingerprint;

    @Value("${elastic.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${elastic.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo(String.format("%s:%s", host, port))
                .usingSsl(TransportUtils.sslContextFromCaFingerprint(fingerprint))
                .withBasicAuth(user, password)
                .withClientConfigurer(
                    ElasticsearchClientConfigurationCallback.from(
                        httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                            .disableAuthCaching()
                            .setDefaultHeaders(
                                    List.of(new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())))
                            .addInterceptorLast(
                                    (HttpResponseInterceptor) (response, context) -> response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch"))
                    )
                )
                .build();
    }

}
```